# Problems building a Flash website navigation system using Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am trying to create a functional navigation bar for a website I've created in Flash using Actionscript 3.0. When I go to run the .swf file, I can go from "Home" to "About" just fine, but then it won't let me go back to Home from the About frame. Which I'm assuming is due to this compiler error that keeps showing up:

**TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at website_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()**

Here is the way I've got each page set up in my timeline:

(Screencap of timeline)
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2HFs2WIAohc/TutwoDIE0sI/AAAAAAAAAW4/t1oBnXgQLJE/s594/timeline.png

This is the Actionscript I have coded so far:

```
stop();
btnHome.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showHome)
function showHome (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("home");
}
btnAbout.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showAbout)
function showAbout (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("about");
}

btnGallery.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showGallery)
function showGallery (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("gallery");
}

btnMenu.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showMenu)
function showMenu (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("menu");
}

btnContact.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showContact)
function showContact (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("contact");
}


btnHome2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showHome2)
function showHome2 (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("home");
}
btnAbout2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showAbout2)
function showAbout2 (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("about");
}

btnGallery2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showGallery2)
function showGallery2 (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop(30);
}

btnMenu2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showMenu2)
function showMenu2 (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("menu");
}

btnContact2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, showContact2)
function showContact2 (e:MouseEvent) {
    this.gotoAndStop("contact");
}
```

btnHome2, btnAbout2, etc. are all the instance names I've given the buttons on the About frame (starting frame 20).

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error and why my navigation buttons will not go back and forth to and from each "page" like a normal navigation system?

I have looked up this error on Google, but it doesn't seem to make sense in my case. Frame 1 on the main timeline is clearly named - should it not be working?

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your program throws an error, because your script is in frame 1, but your buttons are in frame 20 - you are trying to add functionality to something that isn't there (yet). Make sure all your instance names are available by the time you add the event listeners, and the buttons should work - though for many reasons it is not a great idea to implement a site navigation this way.

If you want to know [why this is bad practice](http://theflashconnection.com/content/timeline-navigation-trouble), to find out how to do things in a more robust and reusable way, and if you are willing to learn about object-oriented programming, check out [this tutorial](http://theflashconnection.com/content/better-flash-navigation-using-as3-classes).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue. That does make sense. How would I go about adding functionality to this without having to restart the project with a different method? All of the instance names on my Home and About frames are all correctly named, which is why I'm confused at why this isn't working.

Comment: The instances have to be on the stage and correctly named by the time the script is called.  If they have names in other frames, then the script would work there - but it won't help in frame 1.  You can still use your assets and/or copy the frames, but if you want to do it right, there's no getting around starting over. You won't be sorry, though...

Comment: Thank you. I did have the instances in place and named before I added any code at all, but it's still not responding. It's like it's confused by my code. I guess I will have to start over. I took a look at the beginning of the tutorial, but it's just as confusing to me. I guess actionscript isn't my thing unless there's a simple answer. Thanks though.

Comment: Just to make sure (sorry if you know this): When I say "before", I mean _at runtime_, not during editing. Think of the timeline as an actual timeline - what's on the left side is before what's on the right side.